# help needed with shading applied to a certain part of a mesh?

Tags: shaders

tldr :ok so I have a mix shader between glossy bdsf and principled bsdf on a mesh, and there is a part of the mesh I do not want glossy bdsf on, is there a way to control which parts of a mesh a shader is applied on?
more details : i have a hair particle system on the object, and i do not want the glossy bdsf to show up under the hair, and i think there is enough hair and do not want to add more to "fix" the problem.

Comment: You can select different areas of your mesh in edit mode, and assign them their own different materials.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Answer (score 0):

You can:

Select faces of your mesh in edit mode and assign them different materials. This is the easiest, most straightforward way.

Or

Use texture paint to create a black/white mask for the two textures. Combine the two shaders (Put them in the same material) using a Mix Shader, and plug in this mask as the mix factor. This allows for more control, like smooth texture blending and shapes that are not limited to the object's geometry. However, this takes more work to do.